# C# store app getting variable Json data

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps

I got a JSON file which is build as show below. The JSON file is fine (checked it with a JSON checker) The problem is that after "Characteristics" the "title" and "value" of a Characteristics can be variable as you can see below (I made one characteristics completely unlogical just to make clear it really can be anything).

This is my C# code to extract the data: 
Sidenote: its tested without characteristics and that works. The problem is i can not know what the "Title" (left value) of a characteristic can be, it really can be anything. So how can i still extract the characteristics from the file without knowing its value?

edit: I need the value thats between "", maybe you know a better way?

```
foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
        {

            JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
            ProductGroup group = new ProductGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString());

            foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
            {

                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                ProductItem product = new ProductItem(itemObject["ItemNo"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["UnitOfMeasure"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["Delivery"].GetString(),
                                                Convert.ToInt32(itemObject["InPurchaseOrder"].GetString()),
                                                Convert.ToInt32(itemObject["InSalesOrder"].GetString()),
                                                itemObject["ItemBlocked"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["ItemStatus"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["UnitPriceExclVAT"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["PurchasePrice"].GetString(),
                                                itemObject["Margin"].GetString(),
                                                Convert.ToInt32(itemObject["ActualStock"].GetString()),
                                                itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                Convert.ToBoolean(itemObject["IsActivated"].GetString()));

                foreach (JsonValue characteristicValue in itemObject["Characteristics"].GetArray()){
                    JsonObject characteristicObject = characteristicValue.GetObject();
                    ItemCharacteristic characteristic = new ItemCharacteristic(characteristicObject[""].GetString(),
                                                                                                    characteristicObject[""].GetString())
                }
```

Json data:

```
{"Groups":[
{
"UniqueId": "Group1",
"Title": "Electrisch Gereedschap",
"ImagePath": "Assets/Group1.jpg",
"Items":
[
 {
    "ItemNo": "S010005",
    "Description": "Boormachine BOSCH GBM 13-123456",
    "UnitOfMeasure": "STUKS",
    "Delivery" : "2 Weken",
    "InPurchaseOrder" : "10",
    "InSalesOrder" : "49",
    "UnitPriceExclVAT": "90",
    "PurchasePrice": "60",
    "Margin": "30",
    "ActualStock": "100",
    "ItemBlocked" : "Nee",
    "ItemStatus": "Vrijgegeven",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/S010005_Large.jpg",
    "IsActivated": "true",
    "Characteristics":
    [{
        "Merk": "Bosch",
        "Kleur": "Blauw",
        "Prijsklasse": "1-100",
        "Toerental": "1500rpm",
        "Garantie": "1 Jaar"
    }]      
 },
 {
    "ItemNo": "S010006",
    "Description": "Boormachine BOSCH PSB 600RE",
    "UnitOfMeasure": "STUKS",
    "Delivery" : "2 Weken",
    "InPurchaseOrder" : "20",
    "InSalesOrder" : "6",
    "UnitPriceExclVAT": "75",
    "PurchasePrice": "50",
    "Margin": "25",
    "ActualStock": "31",
    "ItemBlocked" : "Nee",
    "ItemStatus": "Vrijgegeven",        
    "ImagePath": "Assets/S010006_Large.jpg",
    "IsActivated": "true",
    "Characteristics":
    [{
        "Fruit": "No",
        "Banana": "No",
        "Speed": "1-100",
        "Spinning": "yes",
        "Time": "1 year"
    }]
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know what the type will be?

Comment: I know it will be a string, thats all. A characteristic can be for example: color : green   OR it can be: RPM : 1200 RPM.  You can check in the JSON file i provided under "Characteristics": edit: the first item has the characteristic "Merk" while the second item has the characteristic "Fruit"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made something that works, if someone ever encounter this problem: this is how i do it.

```
foreach (JsonValue characteristicValue in itemObject["Characteristics"].GetArray()){
                    JsonObject characteristicObject = characteristicValue.GetObject();

                    var toObject = characteristicObject.GetObject();         
                    var lijst = toObject.ToList();

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IJsonValue> characteristics in lijst)
                    {
                        string productCharacteristic = characteristics.Key.ToString();
                        ItemCharacteristic characteristic = new ItemCharacteristic(productCharacteristic, characteristicObject[productCharacteristic].GetString());

                        product.Characteristics.Add(characteristic);
                    }
                }
```

instead of

```
                foreach (JsonValue characteristicValue in itemObject["Characteristics"].GetArray()){
                JsonObject characteristicObject = characteristicValue.GetObject();
                ItemCharacteristic characteristic = new ItemCharacteristic(characteristicObject[""].GetString(),
                                                                                                characteristicObject[""].GetString())
            }
```